# Find MAC address of client connected to ESP32 Bluetooth SPP via esp32-Arduino Bluetooth serial library

Tags: esp32, bluetooth

Let's suppose I'm using Espressif's [Arduino-esp32 Bluetooth Serial library](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/tree/master/libraries/BluetoothSerial) with code similar to the following:

```cpp
#include "BluetoothSerial.h"

// snip

BluetoothSerial bts;
bool firstTime = true;

void setup() {
  bts.begin("bts");
}

void loop() {
  if (firstTime && bts.hasClient()) {
    // somehow get the MAC address of the client that paired & opened a connection
    firstTime = false;
  }
}
```

First, I ran the above code and paired a MacBook Pro to the ESP32.

I then opened a terminal window & ran `system_profiler SPBluetoothDataType`.

Among other things, it gave me:

- the 6-byte MAC address of the laptop's Bluetooth controller
- the 6-byte MAC address of the connected ESP32

I originally thought the following (executed on the ESP32, in `loop()`) would fetch the MAC address of the client connected to the ESP32:

```cpp
uint8_t[6] mac;
bts.getBtAddress(mac);
```

But when I printed it as hex, it matched the MAC address the MacBook said belonged to the ESP32.

Likewise, I was originally under the impression that `ESP.getEfuseMac()` would return the base MAC address from which the ESP32's Ethernet, WiFi, and Bluetooth MAC addresses are all derived, but it returned a value that looks nothing at all like *either one* of the MAC addresses printed by system_profiler.

What do I need to do to get the MAC address of the connected Bluetooth SPP client that's the *reason* the call to `bts.hasClient()` is returning true?